# How to convert String value into boolean

Tags: postman

I have the issue to convert the string value (which is saved as a environment variable) to a boolean before the assertion.

I currently have this in my Postman test:

```
var regDB_p2018 = pm.environment.get("u_p2018");            
pm.expect(jsonData.premiumTO.particip2018).to.deep.equal(regDB_p2018);
```

After run I get the message:

> test Register_User| AssertionError: expected true to deeply equal 'true'

I think the issue is that the environment variable `u_p2018` as this is saved as a string in the file, but in the response message in JSON the value of `jsonData.premiumTO.particip2018` is a boolean.

How can I convert the value of `u_p2018` to boolean before I make the assertion?

**Additional Info**:

In first Request, I set the following value in `script_1` as initial value:

```
pm.environment.set("u_p2018", true);
pm.environment.set("u_p2020", false);
```

Then I make a registration `POST` request in the second Request:

```
 {
    "personId": 0,
    "name": "Sample",
    "email": "sample@gmail.com",
    "account": {

        "userName": "sample@gmail.com",
        "rejectMessage": "",
        "admin": false
    },
    "premiumTO": {
        "name": "Bbthvn",

        "particip2018": true,
        "particip2020": false,
        "address": {
            "addressId": 0,
            "country": "U.S.A",
            "city": "NY",
        },
        "photo": null,
        "quoteVerified": false
    }
}
```

Then in the `script_2` of second request after getting the response message  I do the following check:

```
var var_regDB_p2018 = pm.environment.get("u_p2018");
var var_regDB_p2020 = pm.environment.get("u_p2020");

pm.expect(jsonData.premiumTO.particip2018).to.deep.equal(var_regDB_p2018);
pm.expect(jsonData.premiumTO.particip2020).to.deep.equal(var_regDB_p2020);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Show what you have done in the question. Show what the value of `jsonData.premiumTO.particip2018` is or even better post the response data. You need to expand your questions a lot more and add more details -  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I posted in the main field as it was not accespted as a comment . In part Additional Info: hope it helps.

Comment: If at any point you have additional information to expand the question, you should just add it to that as an update, rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is setting the value to `true` do you need to set this as an environment variable?

```
pm.test("Equal to true", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().myValue).to.equal(true);
});
```

[image: Postman]

So in your example this could be just:

```
pm.expect(jsonData.premiumTO.particip2018).to.equal(true)
pm.expect(jsonData.premiumTO.particip2020).to.equal(false)
```

Or

```
pm.expect(jsonData.premiumTO.particip2018).to.be.true
pm.expect(jsonData.premiumTO.particip2020).to.be.false
```

It might be good to try and understand the [`Chai`](http://chaijs.com/) assertion syntax more and some basic [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp). This will clear up a number of follow up questions that you will have when you're creating your checks.

Comment: I have 2 requests in the first one I do initialize the vars (set) , in the second one I send a POST message for a registration form and take the value from the first script, so beacuase of this I put them in environment vars. 
but still is the same: AssertionError: expected true to equal 'u_p2018'
in postman doc I rerad that the environment vars will be habdeled as string so I need to convert them into boolean. I think this should be the issue but I dont know how

Comment: As you're doing this `pm.environment.set("u_p2018", true);
pm.environment.set("u_p2020", false);` it's not taking the true/false value from anywhere (from a request) because you've manually added it. So I don't see the need to get the value from the environment file to assert against it.

Comment: Hi Danny, sorry for delay answer. I have to send a request for a registration and I want to automize this. So I had the idea all information which user has to enter in frontend in the registration form, set it in a dummy request (e.g. any GET message) so that in prescript I clear all vars and in test script set some values which user already put in the form. (incl. the two boolean vars above) .

Comment: in the next request when I want to send POST request to register web service with user parameter I will take the user parameter from the saved environment (which was set in first dummy request). and in the response to POST request, I check if the value in DB match to that what user has entered also **jsonData.premiumTO.particip2018** match to user input which is var **"u_p2018"**